# Having trouble importing values from Excel into Mathematica

Tags: import, string-manipulation, excel

When I import values from an Excel workbook into Mathematica; for instance:

originalvalues = {111011, 111011.03, 112011, 112021, 112031}

they are imported as:

> `{"111011.`", "111011.`", "112011.`", "112021.`", "112031.`"}`

Notice that the .03 is "lost in translation" for the second term, giving the impression that there are two repeated 111011 values.

I have to use `FullForm` so that they are imported as:

> `{"111011.`",","111011.03", "112011.`", "112021.`", "112031.`"}`

Let's assume that I conform to the above format.

If I evaluate

```
Table[StringJoin["*", ToString[values[[i]]], "*"], {i, 1, Length[values]}]
```

I get

> `{"*111011.03*", "*112011.*", "*112021.*", "*112031.*"}`

If I now attempt to replace the `*` with quotation marks "" around the string values:

```
Table[StringJoin["" "", ToString[values[[i]]], "" ""], {i, 1, Length[values]}]
```

I get a "string" of error messages (no pun intended).

I have two questions:

1. How can I import values from Excel to Mathematica maintaining the original format:

   > `{111011, 111011.03, 112011, 112021, 112031}`

   (i.e.; without having to use `FullForm` and without getting the period and the ` at the end of the values)?
2. How does one insert quotation marks around strings?

Comment: `Import["data_file","CSV"]`

Comment: Do you have a sample Excel spreadsheet and the code you use to import?  I ask as  I import from Excel all the time and do not have issues with numbers as strings. Also, what version of Mathematica are you using.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion corey979 but, I would rather import my data as an Excel workbook.  Edmund; the amount of space that I have to answer your questions is very limited. Yes; I have a matrix sample but, how can I send it to you? I'm using Mathematica version 10.41.

Comment: My import commands:
setDir := 
 Quiet@Check[SetDirectory@DirectoryName@$InputFileName, 
   SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]]
KnowledgeWorksheet = Import["Matrix.xlsx", {"Sheets", "Knowledge Matrix", All}];
HeaderRow = Table[ToString[FullForm[KnowledgeWorksheet[[1]][[j]]]], {j, 1, 955}];
DataTable = Prepend[Table[KnowledgeWorksheet[[i]][[j]], {i, 2, 34}, {j, 1, 955}], Transpose[HeaderRow, {1}]];

Comment: (Continuation)  SOCsToMatch = {"111011.03`", "112011.`", "112021.`", "112031.`"};

subMatrix[data_, socs_] := Transpose[Cases[Transpose@data, {soc_, ___} /; Or @@@ Thread[StringMatchQ[soc, socs]]]]

KnowledgeMatrix = subMatrix[DataMatrix, SOCsToMatch]

Comment: (Continuation) Of course my SOCsToMatch set is usually much larger in size than the above and I would like not having to format a set like:
{{111011.03, 112011, 112021, 112032, etc.} into:
{"111011.03`", "112011.`", "112021.`", "112032.`", etc.};
which I can't to because of the problem with evaluating:
Table[StringJoin[""", ToString[values[[i]]], """], {i, 1, Length[values]}]

My point is that if the data would be imported as:

{{111011.03, 112011, 112021, 112032, etc.} 

I wouldn't have to format it using FullForm in the first place.

Comment: please *edit the question* to add clarifying information. Its about impossible to read in comments.

Comment: It's about the boring  `Precision` problem which make me confused too on exporting list to Excel file,  try the `SetPrecision` function.  Realy Realy confused why the `InputForm` is different from the KeyPressed numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HeaderRow = 
  Table[ToString[KnowledgeWorksheet[[1]][[j]], InputForm], {j, 1, 
    955}];
```

In other words; use ToString[  , InputForm].

On the other hand; to format the SOCs with " " do:

```
SOCsRegularFormat = {111011.03, 112011., 112021., 112031.};

SOCsToMatch = Table[TextString[SOCsRegularFormat[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[SOCsRegularFormat]}]
```